# keras network doesn't train

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

First time I try to make the simplest net. I train it for XOR. It does not work absolutely. Tryed everithing: different activation functions, number of layers, neurons, epoches, batches, optimisers... Everytime result is 1,1,1,1 (accuracy=0.5). Please, help! What I do wrong?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

X = np.array([  [0,0],
                [0,1],
                [1,0],
                [1,1] ])
Y = np.array([[1,0,0,1]]).T

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))  
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax')) 

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics='accuracy')

#Traiting a model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100, batch_size=len(X))

# Prediction
predictions = model.predict(X)
print(predictions)
```

I noticed, that there are always 1/1 at the left side of the output. But, I guess, there must be something like 4/4. May be this is the reason? But I can't understand how to fix it...

Tail of output:

```
...
...
Epoch 97/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 98/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 99/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 100/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 165ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000
[0.0, 0.5]
[[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]]
```

Comment: Think about it, softmax with a single neuron, what output values are possible? (Hint: only a single constant value).

Comment: softmax transforms values to make them sum to 1... if you have only one output and you apply softmax to it, what do you expect will happen?

Comment: In addition to what @Dr.Snoopy and @jakub have said, change your loss function to `binary_crossentropy`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much to all!

Here the working net below. Strange, that it takes too long time for training! I remember, I did the same task but without Keras several years ago. Training was almost instantly (of course without any GPU). But here "Adam optimisation" (with "fast relu" I managed to do only 4 layers net). Seems that that functions has the opposit effect for such simple tasks.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import initializers
 
from keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
 
X = np.array([0,0,
              0,1,
              1,0,
              1,1] )
 
X = X.reshape(4,2).astype("float32")
 
Y = np.array([1,
              0,
              0,
              1] )
Y = Y.reshape(4,1).astype("float32")
 
init_2 = initializers.TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=12345)
 
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=2, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=init_2, bias_initializer=init_2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=init_2, bias_initializer=init_2)) 
 
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
 
 
#Traiting a model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=7000, batch_size=4, verbose=0)
 
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print(scores)
 
# Prediction
predictions = model.predict(X)
print(predictions)
```